# What happens to target creature when Essence Scatter is played?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

When one plays [Essence Scatter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Essence%20Scatter), does the target creature go back to the opponent's hand, or does it go to their graveyard?

Comment: Note: a "creature spell" is a spell that is on the stack and has not yet resolved.  Once a creature is on the battlefield it is a creature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Essence Scatter](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Essence%20Scatter) counters a creature spell, and countering a spell is defined in the [Comprehensive Rules 701.5a](https://media.wizards.com/2021/downloads/MagicCompRules%2020210224.pdf):

> To counter a spell or ability means to cancel it, removing it from the stack. It doesn’t resolve and none of its effects occur. A countered spell is put into its owner’s graveyard.

Note that technically there is never a creature in this case: a spell becomes a creature only when it enters the battlefield.